This phrase doesn't have a temporal meaning vs. This phrase doesn't have any temporal meanings

This phrase doesn't have a temporal meaning
This phrase doesn't have any temporal meanings.

I think both those sentences are correct, right?
On the other hand, I don't think the sentence . . .

This phrase doesn't have any temporal meaning.

. . . is correct, however,  the sentence . . .

There isn't any petrol/gas in the tank.

. . . is correct, right?

It depends whether you understand meaning as a single quality that the phrase might possess, or suppose that the phrase could mean several different things. If you think of meaning  as a quality, then (1) and (3) are both correct and mean the same .

It's a case of countable vs uncountable nouns "We don't have any flour" vs "We don't have any oranges". Meaning can be countable or uncountable.

However, you can say "This phrase doesn't have any temporal meaning" as well, right?

Something can have one meaning or several meanings. What's that got to do with gas or petrol? That said temporal meaning almost sounds like philosophy. In regular English we'd say: a time-related meaning.
